# after pseudo with image not working

Tags: css

I try to get the same wave symbol underneath my headers as shown in this website http://harbr.co/ but it's not working. So far, I have the following CSS:

```
H2::after {
content: url ('images/wave.png');
position: absolute;
}
```

Help?

Comment: Try giving width and height

Comment: Hey, I tried that but it's still not showing up..

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space between `url` and `(`.

```
H2::after {
  content: url('images/wave.png');
  position: absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qst68fLd/

Comment: Doesn't matter, double colon is valid pseudo selector

Comment: When I inspect I see that the ::after is there, it just doesn't show up

Comment: @TessT yes u r right. try with no space after `url`.  url('images/wave.png');

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/qst68fLd/. is your image available in the directory?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body { background-color: gray; }
h2:after {
content: "";
width: 42px;
height: 8px;
background: url('http://harbr.co/wp-content/themes/harbr2015/img/icons/divWave-sprite.png');
background-size: 100px 250px;
background-position: -50px -50px;
position: absolute;
top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h2></h2>
```